# Was Rick aware of the Zombie Apocalypse before he was admitted to the hospital?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In The Walking Dead, Season 1 Episode 1, when Rick wakes up from the hospital, he is surprised to see his surrounding and "all the hell that got loose", although he had seen and shot a little Zombie Girl at an abandoned Gas station.

- Was Rick aware of the fact that there is a disease turning humans to Zombie?

  ```
                                     OR
  ```
- Did he shoot the little girl because she was coming at him?

Comment: I assumed that first scene with the little girl was a "flash forward" to some point after his recovery from the hospital?

Comment: I do not think it was a flash forward. Because after his recovery he was fighting for survival and that scene is not shown anywhere afterwards.

Comment: Couple of forums discussing it as a flash forward, with links to scripts: http://www.roamersandlurkers.com/topic/1892-very-first-scene/, http://www.walkingdeadforums.com/forum/f47/opening-scene-740.html

Comment: @Ash: You should make that an answer.

Comment: @unor: Hmm, I wasn't sure they counted as definitive references though? (I have no way to verify if the "script" linked is actually legit, for example). Might add it anyway, see what the community thinks :)

Comment: Picking Nits: there are **no** zombies in The Walking Dead

Comment: Knowing from Dr. Jenner later in season one that the outbreak had been going for some time before the total collapse, it is quite possible that his sheriff's department had bulletins from the federal government (Homeland Security, CDC, etc) that gave warnings and advisories as the rise of occurrences occurred. Additionally news outlets do like to focus on the odd and graphic nature of disturbing events such as incurable diseases and people eating the faces of others (taped Florida attack). Does Rick put 2 and 2 together. Obviously not in the show, but he could have been told.

Answer (score 14):

I found a couple of forums discussing this issue (many more can be found in search results):

- http://www.roamersandlurkers.com/topic/1892-very-first-scene/ (contains a link to what appears to be the script for the episode, but I can't verify its authenticity).
- http://www.walkingdeadforums.com/forum/f47/opening-scene-740.html

Opinion seems positive that it's a "flash forward" scene, where the "return" to that scene (written to be at the end of the episode) was cut before release.

Comment: It was obviously a _dramatic flash forward_. Rick was shot on the job while hunting some criminal and fell into a coma for a while. That was definitely before the apocalyptic outbreak when he was still responsible for law and order. He probably shot the zombie girl while he was on the road, looking for his family. Good opener for a zombie survival show.

Answer (score 2):

I think the scene before the opening credits has caused a bit of confusion, but to answer the question specifically; No. Rick was not aware of the zombie outbreak before he was admitted to hospital. I think its pretty clear from the events after the opening credits that:

***Everything was fine***

Rick was shot on the job

Passed out and entered into a coma

Admitted to Hospital

***Zombie Outbreak***

He wakes up